# Evaluation of worst running case time for reverse of following algorithm

Tags: double, doubly-linked-list

what will be the Evaluation of worst running case time for this algorithm

```
Node temp=head; //swap head and tail
   head=tail; // head now points to tail
   tail=temp;
Node p=head; //create a node and point to head
while(p!=null)
{ 
    temp=p.next; 
    p.next=p.prev; 
    p.prev=temp; 
    p=p.next;
}
```

Comment: You run through the list from tail to head once, so O(n).

Comment: are you sure about the answer?